# How do I choose the output file directory in Webpack?

Tags: javascript, html, webpack

When I run webpack with "webpack --mode development", it creates a dist folder and put the bundle.js in it. I want it to create and put it in the same directory. How do I do it?

```
    module.exports = {

        entry: "./main.js", //relative to root of the application
        output: {
            filename: "./app.bundle.js" //relative to root of the application
        },
        watchOptions: {
            aggregateTimeout: 300,
            poll: 1000
        }
    }
```

Comment: At first I thought "let me Google that for you", but it seems surprisingly hard to find  upvoted

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can define it with the `path` property e.g.

```js
output: {
  path: __dirname + '/dist',
  filename: 'bundle.js'
}
```

change it to: `path: __dirname,`